# Custom Tile-Based Menu

Tags: 2013

My Client has a huge farm solution and wants everything to be in the same farm solution so I'm restricted with the options of web parts.

They want their custom tile menu **NOT using the Promoted Links** (long story, but there is no negotiation)

So I have 2 questions:

1. I want to do this in a proper way. Do you think creating a custom
   list, then picking up the items based on the category selected in
   web part options, and rendering as a menu inside the web part code
   is a good way to do this? (Not a visual web part but a normal one)
2. I wish I could do this in a client web part (Add-in part?) But I
   cannot find this option when I am inside their farm solution. When I
   create an Add-in Project the Option is there though but I am not
   allowed to do this. Is there a trick to add a Client side web part
   into a farm solution?

Comment: Why not Visual Web Part (Farm Solution)?

Comment: I'd thought I'd have more control on html elements in a normal web part? But yes can do a visual web part as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any harm on using Visual Web part. Its easy and you have the full control on it. Having a custom list in the back end with appropriate fields will empower your users to easily add and edit the menu items.

Since its a visual web part, you have a flat canvas on which you can paint any type of tile design. Also writing server object model code is fairly easy and I don't think so there are any complications in pulling out the list items.

Comment: I just feel a bit frustrated as SharePoint seems to be moving to client side development, and I still try to do traditional web parts (which people kept saying 'will die' but most places love them, I don't know if this is ever going to happen.)

Comment: @ova You are correct, the new SharePoint Framework is totally JavaScript based.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a Visual Web part, I used this ready -made tiles : http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs
Created a list for logging each tile as an item and allowing person to pick colour. Also have a category option on the web part custom properties so they can create more than one menu.